# Android/Vuforia Error E/IMGSRV 3463

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, size, buffer, vuforia

When I try to start the tutorial app "UserDefinedTargets.unity" from "qualcomms vuforia" on my Galaxy Nexus (Android 4.3), the phone crashes and reboots.
The logcat shows me the following:

> E/IMGSRV ( 3463): :0: Index offset 1698172960 is larger than index
>   buffer size

I am using Unity and the app works fine on my PC with the webcam.
I did also some other tutorials with qualcomms vuforia and they all work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're probably using the wrong Build Settings.
Try changing your `Other Settings` > `Graphics Level` to `OpenGL ES2.0`
It shouldn't be `Automatic`, or `OpenGL ES3.0`or `OpenGL ES1.x`

If this doesn't work, please post your Build Settings window in the question.